# Is there a non-blocking form of Zlib::GzipReader?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, gzip, celluloid

I'm attempting to implement a streaming Gzip decompressor using `Zlib::GzipReader` reading data from a pipe, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in a non-blocking way. Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
# In thread A
read, write = IO.pipe

reader = Zlib::GzipReader.new(read) # this blocks

reader.each_line do |line|
  puts "Yay line! #{line}"
end

# In thread B
streaming_http_response do |gzip_chunk|
  write.puts(some_chunk)
end
```

How can I stream the decompressed content without reading the whole compressed string into the reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `Zlib::GzipReader.new` only blocks until it can read the header. After writing some more it worked just fine.